# system.windows.form.key in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I want to use 'Keys' object in WPF.
That's how my code looks like in WinForm

```
 public List<Keys> keysList= new List<Keys>();
```

I want to use this in my WPF app but it can't recognize 'Keys'.
Is there any alternative? I searched the web and found nothing.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Keys' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using the [Key Enumeration Namespace: System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx), where you should be using [Key Enumeration Namespace: System.Windows.Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a `using System.Windows.Input` statement at the top of your form. If that doesn't work, make sure you're referencing `WindowsBase.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the letter s from Keys to be Key

```
 public List<Key> keysList = new List<Key>();
```